# Site verification through dns txt record in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dns

I need website owners to claim their ownership though dns txt record. What's the best approach to accomplish this task using Node.js?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`dns.resolveTxt(domain, callback)` (http://nodejs.org/api/dns.html) should work.